# iOS error with UIAlertController (CGContextAddPath, CGContextAddPath) brings strange behavior in my app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

in my iOS application I get some errors when I try to use the UIAlertController to show some alert information to the user and after the error appears my progress bar is not updating the progress line.

My code looks like this:

```
// create the alert
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

// add an action (button)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

// show the alert
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code runs inside a UIViewController under XCode Version 7.3 (7D175) on a iPhone 6 simulator.

And I'm getting this type of errors:

```
Apr  6 14:36:29  TimerApp[32952] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Apr  6 14:36:29  TimerApp[32952] <Error>: clip: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Apr  6 14:36:29  TimerApp[32952] <Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Apr  6 14:36:31  TimerApp[32952] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Apr  6 14:36:31  TimerApp[32952] <Error>: clip: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Apr  6 14:36:31  TimerApp[32952] <Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

I tried to google for this bug and found some posts to update XCode but my XCode is the latest version. So what can I do to avoid this errors?

Comment: However this deprecated functions are working better than the official way:
https://github.com/Swinny1989/iOS-Swift-Popups

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you showed so the errors are being caused by something else. It is apparently something about your `CGContext` but there is not enough information here to know what.